# Change Swipe Button Title After Completion

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
cell.rightButtons = [MGSwipeButton(title: "Save", backgroundColor:UIColor.redColor(),callback: {
  (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in
  print("Saved")
  return true
}))]
cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition.Rotate3D

return cell
```

This works fine but I want to change the title from "Save" to remove afterward. Tried it many different ways but doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the official project: [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell)
you can obtain the button pressed by calling the delegate method:

```
-(BOOL) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell tappedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) index direction:(MGSwipeDirection)direction fromExpansion:(BOOL) fromExpansion;
/**
 * Delegate method to setup the swipe buttons and swipe/expansion settings
 * Buttons can be any kind of UIView but it's recommended to use the convenience MGSwipeButton class
 * Setting up buttons with this delegate instead of using cell properties improves memory usage because buttons are only created in demand
 * @param swipeTableCell the UITableVieCel to configure. You can get the indexPath using [tableView indexPathForCell:cell]
 * @param direction The swipe direction (left to right or right to left)
 * @param swipeSettings instance to configure the swipe transition and setting (optional)
 * @param expansionSettings instance to configure button expansions (optional)
 * @return Buttons array
 **/
```

In **Swift** you can write:

```
func swipeTableCell(cell: MGSwipeTableCell!, tappedButtonAtIndex index: Int, direction: MGSwipeDirection, fromExpansion: Bool) -> Bool {
    if let button = cell.rightbuttons[index] {
        print(button.titleLabel.text)
        button.setTitle("Button Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        ... (do whatever you want with your tapped button..)
    }
}
```

To help you can launch the **MGSwipeDemo** project included in the bundle source, and add these lines in objective c like in this screenshots:

```
-(BOOL) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell tappedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) index direction:(MGSwipeDirection)direction fromExpansion:(BOOL) fromExpansion
{
    ...
    if (direction == MGSwipeDirectionRightToLeft && index == 1) {
        NSLog(@"more pressed");
        id button = cell.rightButtons[index];
        UIButton *pressedBtn = button;
        [pressedBtn setTitle:@"Less" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"pressedBtn title: %@",pressedBtn.titleLabel.text);

    }
    ... 
}
```

[image: MGSwipeDemo]

[image: iPhone Simulator before]

### [image: iPhone Simulator after]

*P.S.: update: this part was added to help during comments:*

About your personal project you must add to your datasource any boolean var, i make an example (in Swift code):

```
Class rowData{
   var title: String! = String()
   var subTitle:String! = String()
   var button1Title : String! = String()
   var button2Title : String! = String()
   var isSaved : Bool! = false
}
var myDataSource : [rowData]! = [rowData]()
```

So, when you had populate your datasource you can use the delegate:

```
func swipeTableCell(cell: MGSwipeTableCell!, tappedButtonAtIndex index: Int, direction: MGSwipeDirection, fromExpansion: Bool) -> Bool {
...
    if (direction == MGSwipeDirection.RightToLeft && index == 2){ 
        if let _= cell?.rightButtons[index]{
           let cellData:rowData = myDataSource[index]
           if cellData.isSaved { 
                cellData.buttonTitle1 = "Just saved"
                cellData.isSaved = true
           } else {
                cellData.buttonTitle1 = "Save"
                cellData.isSaved = false
           }
           myDataSource[index] = cellData
           // datasource is modified so launch reload data to refresh layout and call cellForRow..
          // There are other softly methods than reloadData to update tableView layout but I use it just for example..
          self.tableView.reloadData()
        } 
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Obtaining the button press event is not the problem. The issue is that I want to change the title from "Saved" to "Remove" after an item has been saved. The functionality works but the title stays the same. When I swipe again, I get the same title.

Comment: First of all try to see if you obtain the button. Next work try to change the title, im here to help you. PS I have a working project here where i can modified the button titles with the method described in my answer. If you cannot obtain the button in this delegate, probably you had a problem with button creation and delegation settings..

Comment: Thanks. Your example works. Do I need to manually tie the Delegate method to the buttons somehow? I just implemented the same code in Swift and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You're welcome , look for MGSwipeTableCell/MGSwipeTableCell.h the lines that report "delegate" explanation comment. PS If you like this answer please report as answer choosed for this question.

Comment: I am running into another problem with this method. I cannot seem to access  `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyViewCell` any more from the delegate method?

Comment: Have you had already added this line in the viewload method? : tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyViewCell", bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyViewCell")

Comment: I just did but it doesn't seem to be solving the the issue at hand. All I want is to access a label in the cell (similar to the tableView method) in the delegate method. Thoughts?

Comment: All you must to do in the delegate method is to retrieve the current path index selected :  NSIndexPath * currentIndexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; After that with currentIndexPath.row you can access and modify your datasource array correctly..

Comment: Thanks. Want to perform two actions with one button based on its caption. Here's my code.`if (direction == MGSwipeDirection.RightToLeft && index == 2){
        if let button = cell?.rightButtons[index]{
            if button.currentTitle == "Save"{
                print ("item saved")
                button.setTitle("Don't Save", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        else  if button.currentTitle == "Don't Save"{
                print ("item removed")
                button.setTitle("Save", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
          
            }
        }` This doesn't work

Comment: You cannot temporal check strings titles of a queue cell: there is not chance to know if layout queued or cached matched with the exact status.You can use a boolean var to store switched status and work with it : var isSaved: Bool = false ......

Comment: What about be the code for the boolean? Any sample would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to be working. I want to perform two actions with one button. From the swipe menu, if I select "Save", it should save the data and change the title to "Don't Save." When I swipe again and click on "Don't Save", it should remove the item and change the caption back to "Save." I am not actually removing anything, I am bookmarking items. So it's just a tag that needs to be removed.

Comment: Your code will always execute the first bit because isSaved is always false.

Comment: Yes, sorry look now there is also isSaved changed.Im plotting from the stackexchange ipad app, it's not simple like browser page.

Comment: Thanks but this is not very consistent. It works on a new item but sometimes returns TRUE when it has to return FALSE. Have been testing it for the past few hours and sometimes it works, other times it doesn't. Don't how it gets set to TRUE or FALSE randomly. Thoughts?

Comment: Official line guides reccomended to change datasource to modify tableview layout, otherwise you can have inconsistent values due to cache values. In this case we working around a custom class, but approch is the same

Comment: Thanks. Managed to get it working. Now I am facing another problem. Some rows in my table are quite long. They take up more than the height of the phone screen. If a user scrolls to the bottom and swipes, the buttons labels stay at the top. Is there a way to make the buttons visible when a user swipes at the bottom of a long table row?

Comment: Good, Im happy to help you but we must follow the stackoverflow rules. I know also your last answer but you must compile another question, please be detailed as possible and report here the link in these comments with: please can you see this question [the link], so i can go and see your question.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please take a look at this and see if you can answer it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589673/swipe-actions-buttons-locations-for-long-rows Appreciate your help.