# Swipe actions buttons locations for long rows

Tags: xcode, swift, swipe

I am working on a project where I am implementing a swipe menu option for some additional actions. Everything works fine when the height of rows is relatively small and the user is in the middle of the row. But when the height increases, specially when it covers the whole page and the user has scrolled half way, it kind of breaks the design. Here are the screenshots for both actions.

[The image at the top shows the menu when the user is in the middle of the row. The second image show when he has scrolled half way][2]

[image]

My questions is, is there a way to move the actions button down with the page when the user scrolls so they are always visible?

NOTE: I am using the mgswipeTableCell lib.

Comment: NO, But if you can scroll your cell to top and set the buttons in swipe cell as top of it in stead of doing it in centre.

Comment: @Sourav The swipe buttons are always centered no matter what. I want them to be contextual to the visible area of the cell on the screen.

Comment: you change in mgSwipeCell for your convenient frame of swipe button .

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [official project](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell/tree/master/demo) there are 3 available demo, each demo have a custom `UITableViewCell` cell based on `MGSwipeTableCell` methods. It can't be simple if you don't have convenience with `UITableViewCell` subclassing. You can try to following `MGSwipeTableCell` project instructions.
What do you want is to make cell labels with more than 2 or 3 lines and with the buttons vertical center aligned.

The demo who is near your needs is [Mail Demo](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell/tree/master/demo/MailAppDemo)

Comment: That's not the problem. Everything is vertically aligned and works fine for a text the size of the Mail Demo project. The issue is with larger text, say with 20 lines. If the user scrolls up and then swipes, the labels will move up. I also tried adding more text to the mail project but cannot seem to increase the height of the cells.

Comment: There is not issue here, it's just a matter to customize your cell, speaking about Mail Demo what about this property _mailMessage.scrollEnabled = NO; ? Have you try to change it?

Comment: Did you click on the link I have posted? The first image is when the user scrolls up. I have tried that. It just hides the text in your cell, which is something I don't want.

Comment: I've just see your images. What do you want is not included in MGSwipeTableCell proj. You must intercept the MGSwipeTableCell scrolling delegates and center the buttons .IMHO what do you want is unconfortable: you have a vertical swiping table + vertical scrolling inside cell. Seems the same happened with today extensions vertical scrolling and table scrolling extension: it's deprecated. From Apple note: Avoid putting a scroll view inside a Today widget. It’s difficult for users to scroll within a widget without inadvertently scrolling the Today view.

Comment: No. My view is very similar to what the Mail app has. No scrolling inside the cells, etc. Some cells have large text some have small two lines. When the text is many lines users have to read half of it at the top and then scroll to get to the bottom. Now when he is at the bottom of the screen, the swipe menu will have moved to the top, which misplaces the icons.

Comment: With the scroll disable you must respect the containerView cell height. In fact, inside the source code, you can view at the end of swipe animations, buttons reallined with center of the containerView cell. I dont know your code, if you use autolayout or not, if your constraints are aligned or not, in your xib design or your programmatic construction you have to respect your containerView height.

Comment: I use autolayouts and my code is very similar to what I have posted in my other answer. I just create a simple array and use that as my buttons. I couldnt find the code you are referring to in your comment. Can you please post it in your answer?

Comment: Sure, you can find all the swipe animation methods inside the source code project at the MGSwipeTableCell.m module. During the mail demo the message texts respect the 2 lines as you see, Why dont your project respect this limitation? I've tested a message with the long Lorem Ipsum text, the message show me always 2 rows. Check your code..

Comment: I dont want to show two lines. I want to show all the lines.

Comment: What I try to explain to you :) is that the source code is maded to work only with 2 message lines, if you want to increase these restrinction, you must rebuild your cell from XIB with a custom cell, or from code (from code it's very hard) but, surely, you can use maildemo code to starting your customizations..as I write in my answer.

Comment: Thanks man. Let me see what I can come up with. I will keep the progress posted here. Thanks again for the help.